# How to convert several rows from a source flat file into a single column

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud

How to convert several rows into a single column using Informatica Cloud or Power Center?

I've tried using aggregator transformation however is not working

[image]

What I need is like the example above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll look like:

```
SOURCE >> SOURCE QUALIFIER >> SORTER >> EXPRESSION >> AGGREGATOR >> TARGET
```

In SORTER transformation set sorting key for NUM column.
In EXPRESSION transformation after NUM and COD ports add four new ports and assign next expressions:

```
v_COD (variable) = iif(NUM = v_prev_NUM, v_prev_COD||', '||COD, COD)
v_prev_COD (variable) = v_COD
out_COD (output) = v_prev_COD
v_prev_NUM (variable) = NUM
```

Connect NUM and out_COD to AGGREGATOR transformation.
In AGGREGATOR transformation set Group by key to NUM port and check Sorted Input property.
Next is TARGET… 
That’s it!